# Access token warning when logging in using Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

sdk.js?hash=42d52a9c0ddc4f19cfb50e5147eaca5d:49 You are overriding current access token, that means some other app is expecting different access token and you will probably break things. Please consider passing access_token directly to API parameters instead of overriding the global settings.

Comment: What are you doing to get that error?